# Qt Default Stylesheet syntax

Tags: qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

I changed a QGroupBox to `border:none;` and now every child also has no border. I do like some of the effect on the child elements, but not the QPushButtons. I tried looking for a way to restore the default look via stylesheet, but I couldn't find a default file or anything. How do I do this via stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use selector, below one is just one way of many:

```
#groupBox,#progressBar{border:none}
```

There suppose groupBox has a progressBar and a pushButton and these are their names.
Since we have not mentioned pushButton there hence stylesheet will not apply to that.